# Reaction of Methyl Cyanide with nitroethane

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, nitro-compounds

I want to know the products of reaction of Methyl Cyanide with nitroethane in presence of (Sodium ethoxide + ethanol) and then hydrolysed in concentrated Acidic medium.

According to me ,reaction should be like shown in below picture[image: Reaction]

Can anyone confirm me if mine is correct?
If not,then please tell the correct products.Thanks!

Comment: look up the Nef reaction

Comment: @Waylander That contains the hydrolysis of nitro group part and seeing that I think mine is correct.Thanks.

Comment: Except for the carbon atom with 5 bonds. And is this really only a 'hydrolysis'?

Comment: @user6376297 that carbon atom is a typo ,remove H from there :p. And yes,it is Hydrolysis in Acidic medium(with concentrated acid)+heat

Comment: @Ashutosh yes, I imagined it was a typo, but you know, if this were a test, they would not forgive that. The small pain I'm causing to your brain by pointing this out might help you avoid this mistake when it matters :)

Comment: Concerning the hydrolysis: if you boil a carboxylic acid ester with water and a catalyst, you get an alcohol and an acid. None of the atoms involved changes oxidation state. In your reaction, would you say it's the same? See [this](http://www.people.uniurb.it/GiovanniPiersanti/organica2/Lectures/05_Redox%20Neutral%20reactions.pdf) and [this](https://www.thevespiary.org/rhodium/Rhodium/pdf/nef.reaction.review.2004.pdf). So I was pointing out the fact that there's more to it than just addition of water followed by some cleavage.

Comment: @user6376297 Yes I appreciate you correcting my mistake ,sorry if it looked like I didn't . And Yes,I saw the links you shared and conversion of nitro into ketone looks more than _just_ addition of water. Maybe because I am high school student so my teacher didn't want to go into detail and just told us that this is hydrolysis.Though ,seeing nef reaction I guess my product looks correct? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Sodium ethyl nitronate is not a strong enough nucleophile to attack the sp carbon in acetonitrile (commonly used as a solvent because of low reactivity). The possible reaction may be the hydrolysis of acetonitrile to sodium acetate by NaOH which is present as an impurity in the preparation of NaOEt.